# Multiple Binary Search in Array/List

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, arraylist, binary-search

**This is the common program to perform binary search**

```py
def binary_search(lst,num):
    fl=0
    low=0
    high=len(lst)
    while low<=high :
        mid=int((low+high)/2)
        if lst[mid]==num :
            fl=1
            print ('Number Found at index:',mid)
            break
        elif lst[mid]>num :
            low=mid+1
        else :
            high=mid-1
    if fl==0 :
        print ('Number Not Found')
lst=eval(input("Enter a sorted list:")
num=int(input("Enter a number to find:")
binary_search(lst,num)
```

**QUESTION**
What should I do if I want to search and print the index of the element if it is present more than 1 times in the list/array
**Example:** List= [1,1,1,2,3,4,5]
I want to search 1 and it is present 3 times so I want to print all 3 indexes like:-

Number Found at index: 0
Number Found at index: 1
Number Found at index: 2

**(BINARY SEARCH IS COMPULSORY)**

Comment: There are two approaches you could take:  (1) Once you find an element, you could scan backward and forward to find the first and last, or (2) You could do two binary searches, one which finds the first instance and one which finds the last instance.  Which one is faster depends on how many duplicates you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do what you are asking:

```py
def binary_search(lst, num):
    element_found = False
    low = 0
    high = len(lst)
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if lst[mid] == num:
            # Here you have found your element. If the list has several times this values, it will be the neighbours
            element_found = True
            find_equal_neighbours(lst, mid)
            break
        elif lst[mid] < num:
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            high = mid - 1
    if not element_found:
        print('Number Not Found')


def find_equal_neighbours(lst, index):
    low_index = index
    high_index = index
    value = lst[index]
    while low_index - 1 >= 0 and lst[low_index - 1] == value:
        low_index -= 1
    while high_index + 1 < len(lst) and lst[high_index + 1] == value:
        high_index += 1
    for i in range(low_index, high_index + 1):
        print('Number Found at index:', i)


lst = [1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5]
num = 1
binary_search(lst, num)
```

Once you have found the element you want with the binary search, if the list has other elements with the same values, they will be next to your element (because this is a sorted list).
The function `find_equal_neigbours(lst, index)` prints all the indexes of the neigbhours values equal to the element at the index `index` in the list `lst`.

It prints:

```
Number Found at index: 0
Number Found at index: 1
Number Found at index: 2
```

Comment: That's the first of the two approaches I described.  It will work well if there aren't too many duplicates, but in the worst case (i.e. all elements the same) it's O(n).  The other solution is O(log(n)) in the worst case, but slower when there are only a few duplicates.